Has Donald Trump provided any details as to how he would like to repeal birthright citizenship?
According to the New York Times:

As for birthright citizenship, Mr. Trump said he would try to reverse
the constitutional guarantee that anyone born in the United States is
a citizen regardless of the status of their parents. Most legal
scholars have said the president has no power to overturn the right to
citizenship guaranteed by the 14th Amendment, which says that “all
persons born” in the United States “are citizens of the United
States.”
Mr. Trump was vague about how he would proceed and whether he would
seek to reverse the common interpretation of the amendment through
executive action that would surely be challenged in the courts. He
left open the idea that he would instead have to amend the
Constitution, which would be unlikely to happen since it would require
either a constitutional convention or the support of two-thirds of
both houses of Congress and the approval of three-quarters of the
states.
“We’re going to have to get it changed,” Mr. Trump said. “We’ll maybe
have to go back to the people. But we have to end it.”

Has Trump, or any person closely associated with him, specified or commented on a plan to remove the right to birthright citizenship in the United States?

Related: Why can't Donald Trump revoke birthright citizenship?.

Dear downvoters, please explain why you downvoted. Note that 'I believe Trumps plan to revoke birthright citizenship is a terrible idea'  is a perfectly fine opinion to have but is not a valid reason to downvote this question. pigrammer is a new contributor, please be nice.

Not a downvote but we know little more than what is already in the cited article and in the linked other question. It seems the NY times already has investigated all there is.

Yeah, there's no evidence of research and equally no evidence that research would be worthwhile.

Note that its duplicate is 6 years old.  Plenty has changed since, even if the politician involved remains the same.

Why was this closed?  NoDataDumpNoContribution, user182601, Drunk Cynic, Joe W, Ian Kemp. provide explaination!!!

@max Explanation is given below the close reason. You just need to study it. This question is a duplicate and has already been asked and answered, is the opinion of the close voters. And although the duplicate is 6 years old, the matter at hand is even older and nothing of significance has changed since then. There is nothing you can learn here that you didn't already knew by reading there.

The most detailed statement I can find, by far, is this one on Trump's website: https://www.donaldjtrump.com/agenda47/agenda47-day-one-executive-order-ending-citizenship-for-children-of-illegals-and-outlawing-birth-tourism
This statement commits to issuing an executive order on day one of the administration. It does not address the obvious question of constitutionality beyond this vague assertion which would very likely be challenged in court:

It will explain the clear meaning of the 14th Amendment, that U.S. Citizenship extends only to those both born in AND “subject to the jurisdiction” of the United States.


Of course, everyone knows that the clear meaning of the 14th is that being "subject to the jurisdiction" of the US is one of the elements of birthright citizenship; the problem is that illegal aliens are subject to the jurisdiction of the US.  This is why only a constitutional amendment can change the fact that children born in the US of illegal aliens are US citizens.  The Supreme Court will have to devise some serious contortions to find otherwise.

@phoog  Agree it would overturn a major precent, but the 1898 case that interpreted "subject to the jurisdiction" was a 6-2 decision. Contemporary reactions suggested "the fact that the decision of the court was not unanimous indicates that the question is at least debatable." "Everyone knows" the clear meaning of the term, except 20% of the Supreme Court at the time, as well as the many modern legislators who have tried to end birthright citizenship. A constitutional amendment may not be needed to end birthright citizenship, if the SC breaks the precedent of what the term means.

@phoog, the court has ruled both ways, and with dissent, so "everyone knows" is an overstatement. But yes, that has been the prevailing interpretation for the last 120 years.

@PaulDraper what both ways?  Nobody has seriously asserted that the amendment means anything other than "that U.S. Citizenship extends only to those both born in AND “subject to the jurisdiction” of the United States"; the quoted text is basically meaningless. The dispute isn't about whether "subject to the jurisdiction thereof" is part of the amendment; the dispute is about what it means. If you are aware of a court that has adopted the interpretation favored by the incoming administration, please identify the case, because every case I'm aware of adopts the interpretation of Plyler v. Doe.

Yes. An executive order to federal agencies to stop granting citizenship (SSN, etc) to children of illegal immigrants.

On Day One, President Trump will sign an Executive Order to stop federal agencies from granting automatic U.S. citizenship to the children of illegal aliens.
It will explain the clear meaning of the 14th Amendment, that U.S. Citizenship extends only to those both born in AND “subject to the jurisdiction” of the United States. [1]

Undoubtedly, this executive order would be contested in court. There are two major possible arguments for its constitutionality, one of which was explicitly mentioned by Trump himself:
1. Children of foreign citizens are excluded by the qualifier "subject to the jurisdiction."
The Supreme Court ruled in the Slaughter-House Cases (1873):

The phrase 'subject to its jurisdiction' was intended to exclude from its operation children of ministers, consuls, and citizens or subjects of foreign States born within the United States.

That decision was later overturned in United States v Won Kim Ark (1898).
2. Mass illegal immigration qualifies foreign invasion, and therefore outside application.
Trump-nominated James Ho of the 5th US Circuit Court of Appeals recently made this argument in an interview:

But birthright citizenship obviously doesn’t apply in case of war or invasion. No one to my knowledge has ever argued that the children of invading aliens are entitled to birthright citizenship. And I can’t imagine what the legal argument for that would be. [2]


Whether the courts would be likely to agree with these arguments is entirely another question, but an executive order (and winning the subsequent judicial challenge) is his stated plan.

[1] https://www.donaldjtrump.com/agenda47/agenda47-day-one-executive-order-ending-citizenship-for-children-of-illegals-and-outlawing-birth-tourism
[2] https://www.cnn.com/2024/12/10/politics/birthright-citizenship-trump-what-matters/index.html

The (mis-) characterization of the 14th amendment's citizenship clause that appears in the Slaughter-House Cases is not a ruling but dicta: the case was not about the application of the citizenship clause to individuals but about the meaning of citizenship "of the United States" for the purposes of the privileges or immunities clause.  I say "mischaracterization" because it is nonsensical to exclude "children of minister, consuls, and citizens or subjects of foreign states" -- there is no need to mention ministers and consuls explicitly if you're excluding all foreigners.
